# Typescript, type unknown must have Symbol iterator

Tags: typescript

I get this error in vscode **Type 'unknown' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.** for this line `bookmarks.push(...this.$auth.user?.bookmarks);`

```
let bookmarks = [];

    if(this.$auth.user?.bookmarks) {
      bookmarks.push(...this.$auth.user?.bookmarks);
    }
  

    if(bookmarks.length>0) {
```

How do i solve?  When i check `console.log(this.$auth.user?.bookmarks)` , it returns an empty array(length 0)

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now we don't know what `this` is.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let bookmarks = [];

    if(this.$auth.user?.bookmarks) {
      bookmarks.push(...[this.$auth.user?.bookmarks]);
    }
```

In order to use the spread operator with an object, you need to assign it to an object. So in order to assign it to an array, you need to convert it to an array first.